# Problem returning specific view in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view file structure like:

```
Views
   Company
      Department
      Employee
          ManageEmployee.cshtml
```

and the controller is

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
 {
    public ActionResult Index(int dptId)
    {
            var loadedEmp = getEmpOf(dptId);
            return View("Company/Employee/ManageEmployee", loadedEmp);
     }
}
```

But the controller give me an error - telling that it can't find the view.These are the paths it search.

```
~/Views/Employee/Company/Employee/ManageEmployees.aspx
~/Views/Employee/Company/Employee/ManageEmployees.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Company/Employee/ManageEmployees.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Company/Employee/ManageEmployee.ascx
~/Views/Employee/Company/Employee/ManageEmployee.cshtml
~/Views/Employee/Company/Employee/ManageEmployee.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Company/Employee/ManageEmployee.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Company/Employee/ManageEmployee.vbhtml
```

Basically if I'm able to eliminate the **Employee** section, the engine will find it.

~/Views/**Employee**/Company/Employee/ManageEmployee.cshtml **to this**

~/Views/Company/Employee/ManageEmployee.cshtml

Any insights on how to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: A bit irrelevant/slightly related, but maybe consider using T4MVC? This will avoid `magic strings`. It definitely helps when manually entering view names - http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC

Comment: *You have two options here*

**Option #1**

*Create the Company/Department/Employee Directory inside **Shared Folder**. You can locate the Shared Folder inside the View Folder of Root Directory.*

**Option #2**

*Create the Employee/Company/Department/Employee Directory indide View Directory of your Root Folder.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow MVCs convention of ControllerNameController for your controller and your view structure of ControllerName/...

If you want full control over your structure you'll need to switch to a different framework like [FubuMVC](http://mvc.fubu-project.org/).

Comment: Absolutely, I need to follow MVCs convention. What I did to resolve my case was to create partial classes of the same controller with different file name,to separate the logic, but have the URl structure I was looking for.  Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried:

```
return View("/Company/Employee/ManageEmployee", loadedEmp);
```

It looks like the engine is trying to return the view relative to your current location in the site rather than from the root of the site.

Answer (score 2):

View has to be returned from the controller in the following way (for Specific View):

```
return View("ManageEmployee", loadedEmp);
```

In MVC, the controller will automatically route to the View name you provided.

`loadedEmp` should be the object you are passing to the view.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your own convention of arranging the views folder structures, it would be better you plug in your own view engine.